# How can I store a huge list into a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

For example:

```py
header = ['a','b','c']
data = ['1','2','3','4','5','6',...,'100']
```

How can I combine each three of the data to match the header?

Expected output:

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you be more clear as to the result you're looking for?  Give an example of the output you want in your question.

Comment: `np.array(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']).reshape(3,-1)`

Comment: Use pandas for labelled data using the headers as column names. Not sure how the question relates to huge files and CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do this.

```
import csv

header = ['a','b','c']
data = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

file = csv.writer(open(f"testing.csv", "a",newline=''))
file.writerow(header)

for i in range(0,len(data),3):
    new_list = data[i:i+3]
    file.writerow(new_list)
```

Here's the screenshot of 'testing.csv':

[image]